# Setting tag to a dynamically generated view in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I `setTag()` to a dynamically generated `View`?

I tried

```
view.setTag(1, tagValue);
```

But I get the Exception

> The key must be application specific resource id

Comment: If you only need one tag, `setTag()` has an overload that doesn't need the `int`.

Comment: yes I only needed one tag and it solved the problem. Thanks a lot. and out of curiosity what if I needed more tags?